# Python3: You cannot use a Python keyword as a function name

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

While working on a python script I got a SyntaxError while splitting my code into functions
code:

```
def pass():
    print("Sol")
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TESTS:\syntax\raise_syntax_error21.py", line 1
    def pass():
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    You cannot use a Python keyword as a function name.

A `SyntaxError` occurs when Python cannot understand your code.
```

Comment: `pass` is a keyword, choose a different name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pass` is a [keyword](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_keywords.asp) in python - it has a special meaning defined by python. Because of that, you can't use "pass" as a function name. Just change the name of your function to something else (not in the list of python keywords...).